# Help with setting up Windsor Kensington bike on CycleOps Mag+ trainer

Tags: trainer, indoor

I love biking and know basically nothing about bikes. Could somebody walk me through what I need to do to set up this [bike](http://www.bikesdirect.com/products/windsor/kensington8.htm#specs) with this [trainer](https://www.cycleops.com/product/mag)? I have no idea how to attach the skewer to my wheel. Thank you!

Comment: You don't have quick release wheels, so you can leave the skewer in the box. For a derailleur bike, you'd basically, follow the directions otherwise for putting the bike into the trainer as if you'd already put the quick release skewer in -- move the resistance unit to the right height, put the bike in, flip the clamp. But with an internal gear hub, the clamping might affect the shift mechanism, so you may need to do some work (see for example, [this link](https://support.kurtkinetic.com/hc/en-us/articles/201424970-Does-the-Kinetic-Bike-Trainer-work-with-a-Shimano-Nexus-3-Speed-Hub-)).

Comment: If you post pics of the bike's dropouts on boths ides, someone might be able to help. Or talk to the people who sold you the trainer on how to use it with an internal gear hub bike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a cyclOps trainer.... The way the attachment works is pretty cool and does not require a quick release.  Essentially, each side of the attachment point is a slotted tube that fits around the axel  (the slots are to make room for quick-release scewers) the non-drive side slotted tube can be threaded in and out to get the tension right for your bike width.  The drive side has a lever that pushes the drive-side slotted tube in and then locks into place  (the bike is secured by clamping using the lever and the non-driveside adjustment).

It is pretty universal, you will place you bike on the trainer, adjust the mag (another handled adjustment) such that when the rear wheel sits on it your non-driveside axle lines up with the non-driveside slotted tube on the trainer...  to tighten the bike-to-the-trainer pull/rotate the lever on the drive side of the trainer.

The first time performing the process will be iterative to ensure you get the adjustments just right so the bicycle is secured to the trainer.  Once done it will be good to go.  To remove the bike just release the trainer driveside lever... to put the bike back on the trainer just line it up and re-engage the lever.